# React popup display:none to display:block

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a problem with CSS or somethings

I want to click at the profile to show a popup "logout" but it doesn't show anything.

At first, I thought there is a mistake at my CSS, but I searched many times for this solution but it still doesn't work.

```
 import React,{useRef,useEffect} from 'react'
 const profileActionRef = useRef(null)
 const toggleProfileActions = () => profileActionRef.current.classList.toggle('show__popup')

<div className='profile'>
            <motion.img 
            whileTap={{scale:1.2}} 
            src={userlogo} 
            alt=''
            onClick={toggleProfileActions}
            />
                  <div className="profile__actions" 
                  ref={profileActionRef}
                  onClick={toggleProfileActions}>
                  
                  { currentUser ? (<span onClick={logout} >Logout</span> ):( <div>
                      <Link to='/signup'>Sigup</Link>
                      <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>

                      </div>)
                  }

                  </div>
          </div>
```

my CSS

```
.nav__icons .profile .profile__actions{
    position: absolute;
    top: 98%;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: var(--card-bg-01);
    line-height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}


.show__popup{
    display: block;
    
}
```

I have no idea how to fix this. If you can tell me how to fix this it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a react issue, it's a css issue: your first css selector is more precise, it has a weight of 3 (https://specificity.keegan.st/), but the `.show__popup` has a weight of only 1 since it's only a single class. So it's apply before the first selector and the display is erased.

To fix that you can add more weight to your second selector:

`.nav__icons .profile .profile__actions .show__popup`